# The space of Riemannian metrics on a given manifold.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, banach-spaces, riemannian-geometry

For a finite-dimensional smooth (Hausdorff, second-countable) manifold $M$, consider the set 
$$\mathcal{Met}(M) = \{ g : g \text{ is a Riemannian metric on }M \}.$$
I'd like to know about the typical differentiable structures one can place on $\mathcal{Met}(M)$, and how are they constructed. More specifically, is this in general an infinite-dimensional Banach or Hilbert manifold? Or perhaps a Fréchet manifold? What if $M$ is compact?

Also, any references containing a good deal of details, proofs, etc. would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the following will help: think about matrix representation of a Riemannian metric, where the matrix entries are smooth functions on the given manifold. That should help :).

Comment: @WNY: That seems to assume the existence of a global frame on the manifold, but there are non-parallelisable manifolds.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what class of Riemannian metrics you mean. As each $g$ is a 2-tensor, they are sections of $T^*M \otimes T^*M$ but do you want $C^0$ sections? $C^\infty$? $L^2$? Once you have decided this, you will have answered your question.

Comment: I want smooth sections, so $C^{\infty}$. Maybe I should've said that explicitly before, but I still don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: @Zhen: Indeed, my answer was "local." Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The space of Riemann metrics on a manifold is contractible.  It's a simple argument -- the space of inner products on a finite-dimensional vector space is an affine space.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I understand the situation, the $C^\infty$-topology makes the space of metrics a Fréchet space but if $M$ is not compact the set $\mathcal{Met}(M)$ is not open in it, and a problem of finding a convenient topology arises.

I found that a very good survey of the question is given in the first part of D.E.Blair's "[Spaces of Metrics and Curvature Functionals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/B8JCK-4P23G56-5/2/0172fd5d19e52a243be9b71c62c37a24)" (Chapter 2 of "Handbook of Differential Geometry", Vol.1, Ed. by F.J.E.Dillen and L.C.A.Verstraelen, Elsevier, 2000).

As for the paper cited by @AlexE it would be convenient to have P.W. Michor's "Manifolds of differentiable mappings" at hand when reading on this subject. It is [available](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/manifolds_of_differentiable_mappings.pdf) on the author's site. One can find there all the necessary foundations including the construction of topologies.

I would love to know more on this subject too.

Comment: No, the space of metrics cannot be a Fréchet space since $0$ is not a metric. Even more, if $g$ is a metric, $-g$ obviously cannot be one. Therefore, the space of metrics is not a vector space. Maybe you meant "a Fréchet manifold"?

Comment: @AlexM. You have spotted a sloppy point. Thanks for that. I should have said something like "locally like a Fréchet space". For the details please refer to e.g. **David G. Ebin**, [On the space of Riemannian metrics](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183529951)

Comment: Does it known that $\mathcal{Met}(M)$ is (path) connected?

Comment: @C.F.G I don't know...

Answer (score 10):

You may want to have a look at the paper

Gil-Medrano, Michor: *The Riemannian Manifold of all Riemannian Metrics*, Quarterly Journal of Mathematics (Oxford) 42 (1991), 183-202

and the references therein.

Also available online at http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/rie-met.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Hamilton's 1982 paper *The inverse function theorem of Nash and Moser* available [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-07-01/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2/) and [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183549049) is also a very good reference.

The space of Riemannian metrics on a compact manifold is a Frechet manifold.